# How to check how many times a recursive function has been called in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, recursion

Supposing a recursive function, for instance:

```
public static int factorial(int n){
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    } else return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

How can I know how many times has been called for each parameter and store them in a `map`? (i.e: 10 times for n=5, 24 times for n=9 etc...)

**EDIT**:

Suppose the goal is to call it from a method like this, and it could be called many times within the program:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> getTheNumberOfOccasionsItHasBeenCalled();
```

Comment: _10 times for n=5, 24 times for n=9 etc_ Do you mean the function is called so many times?? I dont think so...

Comment: @Codebender I didn't said that, never. It's an hypothetical example

Comment: you can check stackTrace or simply put a flag inside your method to count the call numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic solution for the case where you want to call the number of recursions for every possible input value (which in the case of factorial isn't that useful, but it could be in other cases):

```
static int thenumberoftimesiwascalled;

public static int factorial(int n){
    thenumberoftimesiwascalled++;
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    } else return n*factorial(n-1);
} 

...


Map<Integer,Integer> thenumberoftimeshewascalled = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=1;i+100;i++) {
   // reset counter
   thenumberoftimesiwascalled = 0;
   // calculate
   int result = factorial(i);
   System.out.println("called " + thenumberoftimesiwascalled + " times for " + i);
   // stash in Map
   thenumberoftimeshewascalled.put(i,result);
}
```

Doing something useful with the map is left as an exercise, minimal version

```
static public Map<Integer, Integer> getNumberOfTimesCalled() {
   return thenumberoftimeshewascalled; 
}
```

---

Other interpretation, if you only want to count the number of times the function was called externally and not the number of recursions:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> externalcallspervalue = new HashMap<>();

// the actual function, renamed to hide avoid you having to change 
// in all the places it was called:

private static int internalfactorial(int n){
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    } else return n*factorial(n-1);
} 

// and a simple wrapper that does the accounting - and has the same name
// and signature of the original function.

public static int factorial(int n){
   // do the accounting
   Integer ntc = externalcallspervalue.get(i);
   if (ntc==null) { // first time we see this value
      ntc=1;
   } else {
      ntc += 1;
   }
   externalcallspervalue.put(i,ntc);
   // and return the result by calling the hidden internal function
   return internalfactorial(i);
}
```

Now

```
for (int i=1;i+100;i++) {
   int result = factorial(i);
}
```

Will give you `1:1 2:1 3:1` as each value was called once.

Comment: @stackpepe so now you don't want the number of times the function recurses, but the number of "initial calls"???. I mean, executing `factorial(5);factorial(5);` would give result 5:2 ?

Comment: I am still wanting the same, the goal is to check how many times it has been called for different values and store it in a map. So, for instance, you can call factorial(4), factorial(10), factorial(20) and you can store how many times  it has been called for each one.

Comment: @stackpepe We're clearly on different wavelengths here: with your example, do you want so see `4:1 10:1 20:1`, ie, the number of times a function was called "from the outside" or the number of recursions needed to get to a result for each input value. The latter is what I solved, but I'm not sure anymore that that is what you want.

Comment: First of all sorry if I wasn't clear before, but what I want is to get the number of recursions needed to get a result for each input value in a map. However, it will be called "from the outside" with the method I wrote. Comment added in the method for better understanding

Comment: @stackpepe well in that case I think that my original code does what you need. For good order I also added a second plausible case, ie, to account the number of times `factorial` gets called "from the outside". Do you agree that the first code gives you the result you need?

Answer (score 4):

When you return 1, I suppose you could do

```
 StackTraceElement[] sts=Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()
```

And count all the StackTraceElement where the method name is factorial.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is not working for me, when executing from the main I got: [java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589), loggerService.LoggerServiceImpl.main(LoggerServiceImpl.java:103)]

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have `Map<Integer, Integer> map`

```
public static int factorial(int n){
    if (map.containsKey(n)) {
        int times = map.get(n);
        map.put(n, times + 1);
    }
    else {
        map.put(n, 1);
    }

    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    } else return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Then you can query the map anytime to get values needed. map.getOrDefault(5, 0) returns either number of times the method was called where n == 5 or 0 if the method wasn't called with n == 5

Comment: This is wrong... If I call factorial(5), the map will have 5 keys from 1 to 5 with each having a value of 1. I don't think that's what the OP wants...

Comment: It is possible I misunderstood the question